# asp.net core Folder Authorization Policy fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I would like to "protect" a whole folder in an asp.net core Web Application

The authorization fails even though it shouldn't

What doesn't work: (Startup.cs)

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireRole("Admin"));
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin", "RequireAdministratorRole");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Using this method I get an *access denied* response.

surprisingly this **does** work: (Pages/admin/Index.cs)

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{...}
```

This only "protects" the Index page tho...

what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!